# How to include a PHP array Variable inside a MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, variables

I am trying the following:

```
mysql_query("SELECT `lastUpdate` FROM `summoner` WHERE `name` = '$summoner['name']';");
```

But it doesn't work. I think its because of the `'` in `$summoner['name']`.

Any way to workaround without:

```
$summonerName = $summoner['name'];
```

?

Comment: oh, thanks chris85, next time i'll use that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use (no single quotes on the occurance)

```
"SELECT `lastUpdate` FROM `summoner` WHERE `name` = '$summoner[name]'";
```

Or wrap the Whole array with quotes in curly brackets

```
"SELECT `lastUpdate` FROM `summoner` WHERE `name` = '{$summoner['name']}'";
```

Comment: Great! Both working. Thanks mate. I'll add your answer as solution in some minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You really want to use prepared statements and mysqi_*
[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

```
//assume you have $conn made and working
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT `lastUpdate` FROM `summoner` WHERE `name`=?"){
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $summoner['name']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
}

//use $result to loop or whatever...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"SELECT `lastUpdate` FROM `summoner` WHERE `name` = '$summoner[name]'";
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.